# How to Expose Filter to user when using View for EntityReference field Drupal

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-fields

I have an entityreference field on node creation that allows you to select another node. I’d like to be able to let the user filter by content/node type, instead of seeing them all at once. (The nodes being selected are organic groups/group types, but I would think that’d be irrelevant to the problem.)

I tried [entityreference_view_widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget), which is almost perfect, but I can’t get around some AJAX error when using it. (AJAX was turned on, and I've tried their own [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2192923), and a patch for views that was supposed to be related.)

Then I tried entityreference_filter, but it’s either not working, I don't know how to use it, or I’m just unable to find whatever config it might have.

Anybody have a similar use case and solution? It feels like I must be missing something because this seems like it'd be more common.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an alternative to entityreference_view_widget: https://www.drupal.org/project/references_dialog